# Angular 4 Internalization

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, currency-pipe

I'm using Angular 2 localization support for dates and currencies.

The localization setting is done in the main application module level.
Within my app module settings if I configure the `LOCALE_ID` provider magically I have the localization support.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'nl' }
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, if I use the currency pipe on my application as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>' +
            '<div>{{convertNumber | currency}}</div>',
})

export class AppComponent {
   title = 'Currency Test';
   convertNumber = '12.30';
}
```

You can find the working example in this [plnkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/0lh50OHED5d8CBEifEUW?p=preview).

I got this output `USD 12,30`.

The currency rate for Netherlands is not USD.

Based on this issue, I have two questions:

- When I configure the `LOCALE_ID` what is happening exactly? 
  Where's this localization file?
- I don't want to see `USD` or `EUR`, I'd like to see the currency sign itself. (*e.g.* €) In the documentation, the default configuration for currency is the currency sign(€), not the currency text(EUR).

Apparently, the localization file for Angular 2 is wrong.

How can I find this file and edit it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just read the documentation of CurrencyPipe: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html

Answer (score 1):

I've searched through the source code and here are my findings about your issue:

First if you take a look at the `currency` pipe line 159 **[Source1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L159)**

the pipe calls the `formatNumber` method => **[Source2](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L15)**

which returns `NumberFormatter.format`. To this point the `locale` parameter is always carried (but never actually used)

Finally at `NumberFormatter.format` source code **[Source3](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/intl.ts#L37)** it returns a `Intl.NumberFormat`

Take a look at this method from mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

The usage of this method with currency options is like this:

```
var number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// → 123.456,79 €
```

So let's go back to the source code and see where this `currency` option is set in the second parameter.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/intl.ts#L34

One can expect Angular to convert the `locale` parameter to the actual local currency (for example `nl` to `EUR`) but instead it is

```
options.currency = typeof currency == 'string' ? currency : undefined;
```

So if you don't pass a currency input like this:

```
'<div>{{convertNumber | currency:"EUR":true}}</div>',
```

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ln6br8ZKQdCbA8Ejn5Cr?p=preview

Angular will display its default behaviour which is `USD` **[Source4](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L156)**

Comment: I want to add a language support to my project. If I configure it like that, I won't have the option to change the language.

Besides, I'd rather find the location of this localization file and fix it.

Comment: @ankakusu I know :( maybe someone will correct me but Angular doesn't seem to have the locale support for the currency pipe at the moment as I've stated

Comment: @ankakusu First, `nl` is a language, and there is absolutely no reason to pick a specific currency when you set a specific language. All people talking French on the earth don't use the same currency. That would be debatable if you usd nl_NL, but even then, Angular chose just to use USD by default, and let you specify a  currency explicitly if you want something different. Second, as this answer explains, there is no such file to modify. The pipe relies on the standard Intl api, provided by the browser itself (or a polyfill for old browsers).